# View disassembly in XCode 4 (or Xcode 5 or Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, assembly, xcode4, xcode5

I'm having trouble finding much in the way of information about the new XCode layout. How can I view the disassembly of my source file, rather than just the C++ code?

Comment: In newer versions the assistant editor contains the corresponding views: Preprocess, Assembly and Disassembly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937031/xcode-4-preprocessor-output

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Xcode 4.2 (and Xcode 5), you can see the assembly or disassembly for a file by:

1. Showing the assistant editor (command+option+Enter is the default shortcut).
2. In the JumpBar, select the tuxedo icon and select "Assembly" or "Disassembly" from the drop-down list.

You can view the Assembly for a file whether or not you're running the application. Disassembly is only available when the application is running and being debugged.

Comment: ... with the observation that in 6 the tuxedo icon is now four squares linked by bridges. It's the topmost and leftmost thing. It'll be above the line numbers column if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 21):

Follow these simple steps inside of Xcode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works on XCode 10, you just have to make sure you are at a breakpoint.

Answer (score 11):

You can also display disassembly by navigating to:

`Debug->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly` while debugging.

This will display source and disassembly in the main window view.

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 6 you can go to the menu "Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always show disassembly".

Answer (score -5):

From what I read in a very thorough XCode 4 review (http://fireballed.org/linked/2011/03/09/xcode-pilkington/), the ability to show a file as assembly code is now gone in XCode 4.  I guess you could always set a breakpoint in a method, and look at it disassembled in the debugger console with something like the "x/100i" command to treat print out the next 100 instructions in assembly, but that is a lot less convenient.

Comment: In Xcode 4.5 you can see the disassembly alongside the code using OldPeculiar's answer

Comment: Indeed, the functionality was re-introduced back into XCode -- nearly two years later.